# Modular Exponentiation with unknown base

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider $x^a\equiv1 \pmod n$.

Is there a general way to solve for $x$, given $a$ and $n$?

Would knowing the factorization of $n$ make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

If $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_r^{e_r}$ is the factorization of $n$ into prime powers, then you can solve simultaneously (by the Chinese remainder theorem)
$$x^a\equiv 1\mod p_i^{e_i},\quad 1\leq i\leq r,$$
and then assemble the solutions together.  This solution is unique in the range of $0$ to $n-1$.

In particular, if $e_i=1$, then you can use Fermat's little theorem, $x^{p_i-1}\equiv 1\mod p_i$ to simplify the associated congruence.

Comment: For $e_i > 1$, we can use $x^{\phi(p_i^{e_i})} \equiv 1 \mod{p_i^{e_i}}$, where $\phi(p_i^{e_i}) = p_i^{e_i}-p_i^{e_i-1}$.

Comment: Thanks guys, may I ask for a simple example?

Comment: Dirk: Indeed, the specific congruence $x^a\equiv 1 \mod n$ allows more to say.